# How in the logs print line numbers which has errors using Try/Catch (Selenium WD + Java)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.navigate().to(someurl);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    try {
        obj.assertPageTitle1("Title");
        obj.clickButton();
        obj.assertPageTitle2("Title");
        obj.assertPageTitle3("TitleWithError");
    } catch (Error e) {
        System.out.println("Exception is - " + e);
    }
}
```

Log: Exception is - java.lang.AssertionError

How can I add line number(where was error) in the message which show error in log?

Comment: You can: print the error cause; debug the test in your IDE; split the try-catch into 3 blocks; improve your assert methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent called method is appeared in the stacktrace's first element.

Try

`e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();`

Small example:

```
try {
    String s = null;
    s.toLowerCase();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Line number is: " + e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
}
```

**Note:** You can always print stacktrace by using `e.printStackTrace()` to see the more verbose result.

Comment: yes, this method showed the line number with an error, but the number is incorrect, in the code the error on line "118", and in message error line number is "86". You don't know why it is?

Comment: I can guess maybe line 86 catch the `Exception` of line 118 and rethrow it?  But I won't be too sure until I can see the code

Comment: method e.printStackTrace() showed right line) thanks)